# CSV file of text ontaining new lines

Tags: java, file, parsing, csv

I have a text csv file that contains multiple text from different sources. Some of these texts contain '\n' values and this creates problem with the csv parsing. Even if the new lines are enclosed in '"' the Java Weka Csv parser is unable to keep the structure.

Is there any specific way to write to a csv file other than this:

```
"n \n n \n","n \n n \n"
"n \n n \n","n \n n \n"
"n \n n \n","n \n n \n"
"n \n n \n","n \n n \n"
```

Comment: Do the lines contain literal strings consisting of a backslash followed by the letter `n` or actual newlines?  If the fields contain actual newlines and are quoted, any CSV parser should be able to cope with them.  You haven't explained why you believe it's not working.  You will have to explain in more detail what you mean by _"Weka Csv parser is unable to keep the structure"_ and how you know this is happening.

Comment: It's not clear - do you have a problem _parsing_ CSV files containing literal "\n" values, or do you have a problem _writing_ such values? You start by talking about parsing, but then you ask how to write?

Comment: @Jim Garrison The field is enclosed with quotes. However inside the field there are characters as well as new lines. I am using the Weka machine learning tool and it is unable to understandf that the new-line inside the field does not finish the row.

Comment: I don't know anything about Weka, but if that's how it behaves then its CSV parser is incorrectly implemented.  Since it's open-source you may have to find and fix the parser.